# wxEVT_THREAD event randomly gets lost on Windows

Tags: wxwidgets

I have a GUI thread and a network thread. When the network thread has downloaded a file, it notifies the GUI thread via a wxEVT_THREAD event. This always works on Mac but on Windows it sometimes gets lost and does not reach the GUI thread. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong?

I'm using wxWidgets 3.2 and Windows 10 Pro

This is my code to post the event:

```
typedef struct
{
    int   status;
    int   bytesRead;
    int   dataLen;
    char* data;
    int   imageInfoIndex;
} SFTP_STATUS;

//////////

if (parent != NULL) {
    wxThreadEvent event(wxEVT_THREAD, ID_SftpDownloadCompleted);
    event.SetPayload(sftpStatus);
    wxQueueEvent(parent, event.Clone());
}
```

Comment: are you using wxThread or std::thread? Are you asure the file finished downloading? and the event is sent?

Comment: I'm using wxThread. For debugging this issue, I print messages when the download  completes and event has been posted. So I'm very sure the event has  been posted.